# Why isn't my radio button implementation working properly

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to do a onclick alert once the user selected any radio button. However, if the user presses any of the buttons besides the radio button with the name ANVIL, it sends an alert undefined, while if I press the radio button name Anvil, it will alert stating anvil.

```js
function processFlow() {

  var tempType;
  for (var i = 0; i < document.flow_form.flow.length; i++) {
    if (document.flow_form.flow[i].checked) {
      tempType = document.flow_form.flow[i].value;
    }
    alert(tempType);
    //document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = document.flow_form.flow[i].value;
    break;
  }

}
```

```html
 <h1>Position Trigger Messages</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="sheet_column">
    <form name="flow_form">
      <h2>Flow</h2>
      <label class="flow_row">
        <input type="radio" name="flow" value="anvil" onclick="processFlow()" checked>ANVIL</label>
      <br>

      <label class="flow_row">
        <input type="radio" name="flow" value="fx" onclick="processFlow()">FX</label>
      <br>

      <label class="flow_row">
        <input type="radio" name="flow" value="debt" onclick="processFlow()">Debt</label>
      <br>

      <label class="flow_row">
        <input type="radio" name="flow" value="prms_repos" onclick="processFlow()">PRMS Repos</label>
      <br>

      <label class="flow_row">
        <input type="radio" name="flow" value="prms_fx" onclick="processFlow()">PRMS FX</label>
      <br>

      <label class="flow_row">
        <input type="radio" name="flow" value="equity_racs" onclick="processFlow()">Equity options from RACS</label>
      <br>

      <label class="flow_row">
        <input type="radio" name="flow" value="convertible_bonds">Convertible bonds</label>
      <br>

      <label class="flow_row">
        <input type="radio" name="flow" value="firm_derivatives" onclick="processFlow()">Firm derivatives</label>
      <br>

      <label class="flow_row">
        <input type="radio" name="flow" value="stocks" onclick="processFlow()">Stocks</label>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: "break" should be inside the if statement.

Comment: What is the problem? What do you want to happen?

Answer (score 3):

Your alert() and break should be inside the if. Otherwise, when they select anything after the first item, it will alert(tempType) which is undefined, then break, meaning it will never find a match as the loop exited.

```
function processFlow() {

  var tempType;
  for (var i = 0; i < document.flow_form.flow.length; i++) {
    if (document.flow_form.flow[i].checked) {
      tempType = document.flow_form.flow[i].value;
      alert(tempType);
      break;
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your loop and use

```js
document.flow_form.flow.value
```

```js
function processFlow() {
  var tempType = document.flow_form.flow.value;
  alert(tempType);
}
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[name="flow"]'), function(inp) {
  inp.onchange = processFlow;
});
```

```css
label { display: block; }
```

```html
<h1>Position Trigger Messages</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="sheet_column">
    <form name="flow_form">
      <h2>Flow</h2>
      <label class="flow_row">
        <input type="radio" name="flow" value="anvil" checked>
        ANVIL
      </label>
      <label class="flow_row">
        <input type="radio" name="flow" value="fx">
        FX
      </label>
      <label class="flow_row">
        <input type="radio" name="flow" value="debt">
        Debt
      </label>
      <label class="flow_row">
        <input type="radio" name="flow" value="prms_repos">
        PRMS Repos
      </label>
      <label class="flow_row">
        <input type="radio" name="flow" value="prms_fx">
        PRMS FX
      </label>
      <label class="flow_row">
        <input type="radio" name="flow" value="equity_racs">
        Equity options from RACS
      </label>
      <label class="flow_row">
        <input type="radio" name="flow" value="convertible_bonds">
        Convertible bonds
      </label>
      <label class="flow_row">
        <input type="radio" name="flow" value="firm_derivatives">
        Firm derivatives
      </label>
      <label class="flow_row">
        <input type="radio" name="flow" value="stocks">
        Stocks
      </label>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```